JavaScript page visibility event isn't being triggered in Python Selenium tests
My website has a feature that sends data when the page visibility changes to "hidden." It works fine during manual testing but doesn’t trigger in automated testing with Python Selenium. I've also tried using the Page Lifecycle API with the same outcome.
Here's the code snippet:
document.onvisibilitychange = () => {
    if (document.visibilityState === "hidden") {
        sendBeaconData();
    }
};

Is there a possibility to adjust the JavaScript code so it’s detected during automated testing, without making changes to the Selenium setup?
Note: pageunload and similar functions aren't viable solutions, as they don’t work consistently on mobile devices.
I have tried Page Lifecycle API and pagehide event but it provides same result.
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/web-platform/page-lifecycle-api#advice-hidden

+1 .Serious question in some cases(to avoid scrapping), and am unable to find any workaround from javascript side. Anyway reason is selenium being webdriver doesn't support visibility change events.. Following this question, looking for answers..

I think the browser/user-agent only allows access to the API when a user interacts with the document (at least once)... as opposed to script (which is more like what Selenium does... events are "isTrusted" when humans do them)  To test, try clicking inside the window while the test is running.  (or use robot-like framework to do same, or even just set focus)  This would be to avoid people abusing it to do annoying things like bringing it's tab back into focus, or generating popups, or showing an animated staple tapping on the screen, etc...
